# Paracol: vertical line between selected columns

Tags: paracol

How should I do to have vertical line only between the second and the third column? Thank you.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt} 
\setcolumnwidth{0.30\textwidth, 0.30\textwidth,, 0.30\textwidth}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}  

\begin{document}

    \begin{paracol}{3}
    \sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]
        \blindtext[1]
        \switchcolumn[1]
        \blindtext[1]
         \switchcolumn[2]
        \blindtext[1]
    \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try` \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}`.  This also works with twocolumn and multicols.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes vertical line between the first and the second column and also between the second and the third column. I want only the second one. The space between the first and the second column must be without the vertical line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses the everypage package, assuming you want the line on every page.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{0.30\textwidth, 0.30\textwidth,, 0.30\textwidth}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}  

\newlength{\myoffset}
\setlength{\myoffset}{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth + 1.5\columnsep}

\newcommand{\myhook}% cursor is at (1in,1in) and must not be moved.
{\rlap{\ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \hskip\oddsidemargin \else \hskip\evensidepargin \fi
  \hskip\myoffset\raisebox{\dimexpr-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight}[0pt][0pt]%
{\rule{0.5pt}{\textheight}}}}

\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\myhook}% Note: you can also use \AddThispageHook, or use tikzpagenodes

\begin{document}

    \begin{paracol}{3}
    \sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]
        \blindtext[1]
        \switchcolumn[1]
        \blindtext[1]
         \switchcolumn[2]
        \blindtext[1]
    \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses a `\tikzmark` to locate the top of the paracol.  One could also use `(current page text area.north west)` if starting at the top of the page.

Interestingly, placing the `\tikzmark` above the paracol doesn't work.

While both the `\tikzmark` and `tikzpicture` are invisible, they are equivalent to `\hbox{}` and will cause a blank line if followed by `\switchcolumn`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{0.30\textwidth, 0.30\textwidth,, 0.30\textwidth}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}  

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{paracol}{3}
    \sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]
        \noindent\tikzmark{top}\indent
        \blindtext[1]
        \switchcolumn[1]
        \blindtext[1]
        \switchcolumn[2]
        \blindtext[1]
    \end{paracol}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw ($(pic cs:top)+(0.6\textwidth+1.5\columnsep, \ht\strutbox)$) --
    (0.6\textwidth+1.5\columnsep, \ht\strutbox);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I ask you, how the code looks like if it be only a part of one page?

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to use \tikzmark.