# Column separator extends above text if the column is not the first item in the document

Tags: columns, dimensions, paracol

I [previously asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671382/column-separator-extend-above-text/) about the divider line sticking up above the text in columns. The solution posed:

```
\setlength\topskip{7pt}
```

works beautifully, but only if the column is the very first item in the document. All subsequent columns still have the protruding divider line, as in the below example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength\topskip{7pt}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    No problem here...
    \switchcolumn
    Kein Problem hier...
    \end{paracol}

But if it's preceeding by text

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength\topskip{7pt}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    The divider sticks up
    \switchcolumn
    Dann ragt der Teiler nach oben
    \end{paracol}
    
\vspace{1cm}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength\topskip{7pt}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    Same with just space
    \switchcolumn
    Das Gleiche gilt für den leeren Raum
    \end{paracol}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This post with tikzmark may be able to help you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529110/paracol-vertical-line-between-selected-columns/529329#529329

Comment: @pascal974 Thank you. It looks like this would work well if my text were not broken up by full width (single, rather than double column) text. As it is, I have tried playing with this, and I don't believe there is a good solution there, going this route. My hunt continues! Thank you for the attempt.

Comment: I posted an answer, do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

With John Kormylo's code, creating an adjustment command `\adjustment` initilized to `2pt` (seems to be what you expect), we get:
[image]

**The code**

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{paracol}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}

    \newlength{\ajustement}
    \setlength{\ajustement}{2pt}

    \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \noindent\tikzmark{top}\indent
        \blindtext[1]
        \switchcolumn
        \blindtext[2]
    \end{paracol}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[line width=0.4pt] ($(pic cs:top)+(0.5\textwidth, \ht\strutbox-\ajustement)$) -+
        (0.5\textwidth, \ht\strutbox+\ajustement);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```